# How to sum every N-number of cells every M-th row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to sum 3 columns of every other row in Excel.

I know how to do the "sum every 3 columns" part:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A40,0,3*(COLUMN(A40)-(COLUMN($A40)-1))-3,1,3))
```

How do I apply this formula so it sums every other row, starting with A40 ?

So A40, A42, A43 etc.

**Edit**:

Basically, if you look at this picture, I am looking for formula, that would allow to sum every red cell in N3 and then be copy-pasted to sum every yellow  cell in O3.

[image]

Comment: Do you want your formula to sum every other row?

Comment: sorry, looks like I didn't quite explain myself, I will update

Comment: By looking at the example (picture),You may need to sum the yellows ones in N3 and the red ones to O3

Comment: @stpn are you allowed to add an extra column?

Comment: Your N's and M's are incorrect. What you want is to sum every Row or every other row or Rows/2, but columns to X or 3 in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Array** Formulae:

Copy and paste the formula below. 
After you've pasted this, rather than just hitting enter, 
press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

`=SUM(A2:E7*(MOD(ROW(A2:E7),2)=0))`

[image]

### Note:

**MOD or Modulus, is looking at every 2nd Row**, so your yellow row must correspond to **EVEN row numbers**, **regardless of what your region is**.

Comment: This one is better and works smoothly ,, U get +10 ☺

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, if the column you need to sum are consecutive (A,B,C) In O3 write:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(A3:A19),2)=1,A3:C19,""))
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Array Formula)

This formula divide the row number by 2 if the result is 1 (the remain ) `(Mod(Row(),2)=1)` it will add the value of the corresponding cell in the columns(A,B,C) to the sum 
if the remain is 0 it will return ""

In N3 you can just change the rferences:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(D3:D19),2)=1,D3:F19,""))
```

Change the references to correspond your real Data

Answer (score 0):

It is nice to use a formula but I think still the best and easy way is to use a pivot on this, if the bases cell has a unique key (date or something).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133067)